# Python 2.7 Non-ASCII character inside byte string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, ascii

I understand that Python 2.7 byte string only take ASCII character, and I wonder why the following works? Looks like ü was encoded in some other format, can you explain?

```
>>> s = "Flügel"
>>> s
'Fl\x81gel'
```

Comment: No, Python byte strings take *any byte* in the range 0-255 (hex 0x00 through to 0xFF), not just the ASCII range of 0-127 (0x00-0x7F).

Comment: Python 2.7 byte strings take sequences of bytes -- Not just ASCII characters.  Bytes can have arbitrary values from `0x00` -> `0xff`.

Comment: Your terminal sends the byte 0x81 when you type `ü`, so that is what is stored.

Comment: If I paste it into 2.7.13 on my command line I get a `str` with `Fl\xc3\xbcgel`, so either Python or my terminal is dumping in Unicode? That goes to ASCII?

Comment: @NickT; your terminal is configured to communicate in UTF-8, the OP is using a Latin variant (probably a Windows codepage like CP1252). Don't confuse encodings with Unicode; UTF-8 is a codec that can encode all of the Unicode standard, but so can UTF-16 and UTF-32.

Comment: Ah, yup: `sys.stdin.encoding == 'UTF-8'`

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that Python 2.7 byte string only take ASCII character,

You misunderstood. Python byte strings take *any valid bytes*. Bytes are basically integer values in the range 0 through to 255 (ASCII covers 0 through to 127).

When you open the interactive interpreter prompt in a terminal or console, the configuration of that terminal or console determine what bytes you can type and send to Python. You appear to be using one that sends Latin text (a [number of variants](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00FC/codepage_support.htm) send `0x81` for `ü`). Python stored that in the bytestring.

You can check what codec was used by looking at `sys.stdin.encoding`.

Mine is configured to handle UTF-8, which uses *two* bytes to encode the same character ([U+00FC LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS](https://codepoints.net/U+00FC)):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> s = 'Flügel'
>>> s
'Fl\xc3\xbcgel'
```